# Select tag not getting set in ie on select.value in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
cells=document.getElementsByClassName('assetAction');
var selectedDropdown=document.getElementsByClassName('assetSelected');  
for(var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
   selectedDropdown[j].value = 'Change';
```

}

The above javascript code. 
I am setting a select tag which is repeated for a row.

```
<td class="assetAction">
    <select class="assetSelected">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option>Change</option>
        <option>Disconnect</option>
        <option>Renew</option>
        <option>Add Feature</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

somewhat in this format. Also there are multiple such selects. I have an action which sets the option to "change" on click. 
The above code works in firefox but not in IE. 
What am I missing ?
Earlier I was using name for td and select now I changed everything to class.

Comment: could you locate the line of error?..try alerting results like cell.length or selectedDropdown.length.

Comment: Which IE version? Did you know that you're comparing apples to bananas? You're looping through each option element, and stopping when you have reached the number of cells.

Comment: getElementsByClassName not workin in IE so can you use something else like getElementById, or getElementsByTagName and then loop and get your select tag ?

Comment: @Krishnanunni selectedDropdown[j].value seems to be the problem. when I print that it gives a blank but when I do selectedDropdown[j].innerHTML it shows me the selected html. Is this the right way to go for is there any easier way to set the option which is cross browser compatible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cells=document.getElementsByClassName('assetAction');
var selectedDropdown=document.getElementsByClassName('assetSelected');  
for(var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
selectedDropdown[j].options[2].selected=true;}
```

Can you try this?

or also

```
 selectedDropdown[j].options[2].selected="selected";
```

not sure of syntax

Comment: Also i'm not so sure about getElementsByClassName compatibility with IE. However, getElementById or Name works in all.

Comment: name surely did not work I first tried it with name and thats the reason I changed everything to class. ID would probably work but I am making my own HTML table dynamically and it will be little complicated to make the html table with unique ids also using a proprietorial language which is not so flexible.

Comment: selectedDropdown[j].options[2].selected=true; works in both 
Checking a few more things. I also want to read the value of the selected Index without having to read the innerhtml.

Comment: you can read the selected index using the same if(selectedDropdown[j].options[i].selected==true;){s_index=i;}

Comment: var selectedValue = selectedDropdown[j].options[selectedDropdown[j].selectedIndex].text;
I was able to read back the selected value using this.. But over all Your solution worked on both IE and FF. Thanks,

Comment: Yes sure .. I am a newbie here I ticked your answer already .. :) Cheers !!